# IS possible to implement to resize div by mouse using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

IS possible to implement to resize div by mouse using JQuery ? Need to resize just height by dragging bottom line .

Answer (score 2):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for this.  However you might want to check out this thread, [How to let resize vertically a DIV with only jQuery - no plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061099/how-to-let-resize-vertically-a-div-with-only-jquery-no-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out jQuery UI's Resizable. Here's the link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/